# What is the best form of wildcard indication in UI?

Tags: forms

Can anyone help me figure out what is the best way to represent that wildcards are allowed in a field?

[image]

Also, is there a best practice to represent 'enter exact match' as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on preference, however, considering all odds we'll take a look at each option and pick the best, worse of all.

**OPTION A:**

The input label could easily be confused with the wildcard *hint* at such its a no-no.

**OPTION B:**

This would have been a great option, only that if the field is compulsory and/or its possible to have an error, this error; when indicated will be confusing alongside the wildcard *hint*, because from research and usability trends errors in inputs are best indicated *beneath* the input type.

**OPTION C:**

Wildcard *hint* as a placeholder makes a lot of sense, however after the input box *in this case,* has been loaded with data it disappears, resulting in no persistent guideline for the user to follow, but then, this could easily be fixed by reiterating the wildcard *hint* when the error pointed out in *Option B* is visible.

***Summary:*** **Option C** is the best, worse of the three.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate you, dbkonXepts, very much. Your inputs helped me a lot to make a decision on option C. I have a resolve now. Thanks again.

Comment: @karthikrajendran Great!. You can mark it has the right answer. To help others follow through and make the community aware your question has been answered.